# How to match both pattern under one regex?

Tags: python, regex

Raw Data:

```
# Case 1
1980 (reprint 1987)

# Case 2
1980 (1987 reprint)
```

Capture Group:

```
{
    publish: 1980,
    reprint: 1987
}
```

Requirement:

1. Match "reprint" and thus treat its year segment as reprint.
2. First matching year is always the publish year.

Current Approach:

```
# Match 2nd case but not the 1st case.
(?P<publish>\d{4}).*(?P<reprint>\d{4}(?=\sreprint.*))

# Match 1st case but not the 2nd case
(?P<publish>\d{4}).*(?<=reprint\s)(?P<reprint>\d{4})
```

I am not sure how to merge the 2 regex above. So I have to iterate the matching twice. Alternatively, if there is an answer on how we can match both under one regex is far better.

Comment: not sure if `python` tag is appropriate, because I am using python regex metacharacter and i'm working on it using python

Comment: Is your data good representation? Why not assume the `(` and `)` also instead of `.*`?

Comment: @krzyk the data is not in good shape, some data appear as follow. `First Pub 1990 First Reprint 2002`, so I can't match the parentheses.

Comment: It would be good to add such examples in the input of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this single regex with alternation. `reprint` group will match if it is followed by `\sreprint` (asserted by a positive lookahead) or if it preceded by `reprint\s` (asserted by a positive lookbehind).

```
(?P<publish>\d{4}).*?(?P<reprint>(?:\d{4}(?=\sreprint)|(?<=reprint\s)\d{4}))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO4vJ9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just:

```
(?P<publish>\d{4}).*(?:reprint )?(?P<reprint>\d{4})(?: reprint)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/lX7hK5/1

This will assume that the reprint can appear before or after the date, but your raw data suggest that it can be only on one place so it will work (e.g. `1980 (reprint 1987 reprint)`).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is specifying the parenthesis and mixing both regexes:

```
r'(?P<publish>\d{4})\s\(.*(?P<reprint>\d{4}).*\)
```

Demo:

```
>>> [i.groupdict() for i in re.finditer(r'(?P<publish>\d{4})\s\(.*(?P<reprint>\d{4}).*\)', s)]
[{'reprint': '1987', 'publish': '1980'}, {'reprint': '1987', 'publish': '1980'}]
```

If the existence of `reprint` within the parenthesis is necessary you can use a positive lookahead in order to enforce it:

```
>>> s2 = """# Case 1
... 1980 (reprint 1723)
... 
... # Case 2
... 1980 (1987 reprint)"""
>>> 

>>> [i.groupdict() for i in re.finditer(r'(?P<publish>\d{4})\s\(((?=reprint).*)?(?P<reprint>\d{4})((?=\sreprint).*)?\)', s2)]
[{'reprint': '1723', 'publish': '1980'}, {'reprint': '1987', 'publish': '1980'}]
```

Comment: This will also match `1985 (1999)`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, in that case we need to make sure about the whitespace and/or the word.

Comment: What I meant was it doesn't enforce presence of `reprint` keyword inside the `(...)`